# Pascal writing elements from an array?

Tags: arrays, pascal

i have a very simple code here and at the minute when run the console will display 'Your card is the (Random Number) of (Number entered as choice.) When i aim for the console to display the Suit of the card instead of the number entered by the user, i thought the assignment statements would allow that.

```
type
    Suit = array[1..4] of string;

var
  SuitChoice : Suit;
  I : integer;
  SuitName : string;
  Value : Integer;
  Index : integer;
  Choice : string;
begin
  randomize;
  Writeln('What is your suit?');
  readln(SuitChoice[i]);
  SuitChoice[1]:= 'Clubs';
  SuitChoice[2]:= 'Diamonds';
  SuitChoice[3]:= 'Hearts';
  SuitChoice[4]:= 'Spades';

  For index:= 1 to 13
  do
    Value:=Random(index);

  writeln('Your card is the ', Value, ' of ', SuitChoice[i]);
  readln;  
end.
```

Comment: What is the meaning of " i"  ? you don't seem to initialize it.

Comment: `i` is an uninitialized variable when you use it as an index in `SuitChoice[i]`.

Comment: Not only is `i` uninitialized, but you use it to access an array (`SuitChoice`) that you then immediately assign new values to, which would discard what you read into `SuitChoice[i]` anyway.

Comment: Ah that is really obvious and now kind of embarassing must've looked at it for too long, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code you posted. Let's go through them, one at a time:

```
type
    Suit = array[1..4] of string;

var
  SuitChoice : Suit;
  I : integer;
  SuitName : string;
  Value : Integer;
  Index : integer;
  Choice : string;   { You declare but never use this variable, but
                       use i instead. Remove one of them. }
begin
  randomize;
  Writeln('What is your suit?');

  { You use an uninitialized variable to access the SuitChoice[] array }
  readln(SuitChoice[i]);

  { 
    You immediately overwrite anything you might have written (if the
    uninitialized value of i happened to be 1-4) with new values 
  }
  SuitChoice[1]:= 'Clubs';
  SuitChoice[2]:= 'Diamonds';
  SuitChoice[3]:= 'Hearts';
  SuitChoice[4]:= 'Spades';

  { 
    The next lines produce no output except for the final 
    Value := Random(13). There should be a begin..end block
    here, so that both the assignment to Value and the
    WriteLn execute each pass through the loop.
  }
  For index:= 1 to 13 do
    Value:=Random(index);

  writeln('Your card is the ', Value, ' of ', SuitChoice[i]);
  readln;  
end.
```

Putting that all together should give you something more like this:

```
program Cards;

type
    Suit = array[1..4] of string;
var
  SuitChoice : Suit;
  SuitName : string;
  Value : Integer;
  Index : integer;
  Choice : string;
begin
  randomize;

  SuitChoice[1]:= 'Clubs';
  SuitChoice[2]:= 'Diamonds';
  SuitChoice[3]:= 'Hearts';
  SuitChoice[4]:= 'Spades';


  { Write prompt, and read value into i.
  Writeln('What is your suit?');
  readln(Choice);

  { 
    Make sure we execute both the value assignment and the
    WriteLn on each pass through the loop 
  }
  for index:= 1 to 13 do
  begin
    Value := Random(index);
    WriteLn('Your card is the ', Value, ' of ', SuitChoice[Choice]);
  end;

  ReadLn;  
end.
```

Because of the way you're using it, you could improve this slightly by changing your `SuitType` to a constant declaration. It can be done in a single line, and saves the code that initializes each element because it's done at compile-time instead of runtime.

```
const
  SuitChoice: array[1..4] of string = ('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades');
```

You could then remove the `SuitType` type entirely, as well as the 4 lines that initialize it, and change your `WriteLn` statement to

```
WriteLn('Your card is the ', Value, ' of ', SuiteChoice[Choice]);
```

Or, IMO more simply as

```
WriteLn(Format('Your card is the %s of %s', [Value, SuitChoice[Choice]]));
```